# How to call external lib in my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to include `Parse` SDK in my plugin. I created a folder `lib` and put the SDK in it. and called like that in controller:

```
namespace Craft;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseQuery;



    $APPID = 'xx';
    $MASTERKEY = 'xx';
    $RESTKEY = 'xxx';
    $PARSEURL = 'https://api.parse.com/1/';

    $list = new parseQuery('Dance');
    $results = $list->find();
```

And it says: `Fatal error: Class 'Parse\ParseQuery' not found in /vagrant/craft/plugins/xx` not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method we are including libraries in our plugin.

```
namespace Craft
require_once(CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH.'parse/parsequery/xx.php');
```